# vm instanceのMachine type変更方法

Tags: google-compute-engine

リソースが足りなくなってきたので、instanceのMachine typeを変更してスケールアップしたいのですが、IPアドレスを変えずに実現する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPアドレスを変更したくないのであれば、現在利用しているIPアドレスをリザーブする必要があります。
Developer ConsoleからNetworking -> External IP addressesを選んで、現在使っているIPアドレスをStaticに変更してください。

その後、以下の手順を行います。

instanceのboot diskを削除しない設定に変更
instanceを削除
希望のmachine typeでip addrはリザーブしてあるものを指定して、boot diskを元のdiskを指定して、instanceを作成

もし、今回boot diskを残したまま、instanceを削除するのが初めてなのであれば、作業前にboot diskのsnapshotを作っておくことをおすすめします。
また、instanceを1回削除しますので、再度作りなおすまでの間は、applicationがdownすることに注意してください。

Comment: なるほど、External IPなら教えて頂いた方法で同じIPを使えますね。
ちなみにInternal IPを変えずにmachine typeを変える方法はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: Internal IPをはEphemeral IP Onlyですね。Internal IP Addrはインスタンス名からDNSで拾えるようになっているので、Internal IP Addrを直接指定することは無いですねー

Comment: instance nameからIP Addrを引けるとは知りませんでした。
最初から名前でアクセスしておけば、machine typeを変えても他のサーバの設定を変えずに済みそうです。とても助かりました。

Comment: @taro さん 解決したのであれば是非解決済みにしましょう！

Comment: @keisukeoohashi さん、了解しました！